# Handling Errors/Exceptions in a Loop

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, error-handling, exception

I have two corresponding lists:

1. One is a list of items
2. The other is a list of labels for those items

I want to write a function that check if each item in the 1st list is a JSON object. If it is, it should remain in the list but if not, then it and its corresponding label should be deleted.

I wrote the following script to do this:

```
import json 
def check_json (list_of_items, list_of_labels):
    for item in list_of items:
        try:
            json.loads(item)
            break
        except ValueError:
            index_item = list_of_items.index(item)
            list_of_labels.remove(index_item)
            list_of_items.remove(index_item)
```

However, it does not remove items that are not JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to modify the list you are iterating over; it breaks the iterator. Instead, build and return new lists.

```
import json 
def check_json (list_of_items, list_of_labels):
    new_items = []
    new_labels = []
    for item, label in zip(list_of items, list_of_labels):
        try:
            json.loads(item)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        new_items.append(item)
        new_labels.append(label)
    return new_items, new_labels
```

If you insist modifying the original arguments:

```
def check_json (list_of_items, list_of_labels):
    new_items = []
    new_labels = []
    for item, label in zip(list_of items, list_of_labels):
        try:
            json.loads(item)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        new_items.append(item)
        new_labels.append(label)
    list_of_items[:] = new_items
    list_of_labels[:] = new_labels
```

but note that this isn't really any more efficient; it just provides a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list comprehension and unzip it:

```
def is_json(item):
    try:
        json.loads(item)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


temp = [(item, label) for item, label in zip(items, labels) if is_json(item)]
items, labels = zip(*temp)
```